Can you override the default MacOS file transfer system in Finder?
In Windows you can replace the file transfer process/dialog/system with a program like Teracopy. While I don't use Teracopy in Windows, the default file transfer system in Finder is lacking features to make large file transfers faster & ergonomic.
For example, it's not parallel, which is helpful in speeding up moving files between folders on the same NFS or SMB mount.
It's also nice to have a transfer list, non-interactive mode and transfer statistics (like transfer speed and so on).
I am thinking of writing my own implementation, but I am unsure if MacOS offers the ability to replace the default file transfer mechanism with a custom one.
Does anyone know if that is possible without writing a custom kernel extension?

There is a version of Teracopy for Mac.
